# How to set a environment variable using Gradle but not in Exec scope?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, environment-variables

I want to set an environment variable which is **System.env.TEMP** from **initd.gradle** file in init.d folder which should be accessible within the other Gradle projects.

I tried to set it like this in C:\Users\myuser\.gradle\init.d\initd.gradle file.

```
def envVars = [:]
envVars['System.env.TEMP'] += "$buildDir/tmp";
tasks.withType(Exec) { environment << envVars }
```

And I tried to access it from D:\test-workspace\GradleTaskExample\build.gradle file like in the following code.

```
println "$System.env.TEMP";
```

But it prints only the old value. Not the value that I set. So to access it using println command which is in Gradle scope, How can I set the value? If what I'm trying to do is not possible please explain.

Thank  you.

Comment: `envVars['System.env.TEMP']` doesn't have anything to do with environment variables.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Can you please explain why?

Comment: Because `envVars` is a map that you created.  So all you're doing there is adding a key called `System.env.TEMP`.  That doesn't affect your actual environment variables.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Oh I understand now. So how can I do this?